# text border outline gets cut off

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see, 'Lo-fi Wireframing tag' is cut off because of the screen size.

here's the css

```
.card-tag-ux{
  font-size: .9em;
  border:2px solid #A7C8FF;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 2.2em;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to solve? Repositioning the elements to fit the border? Drawing the border beyond the screen?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lvfvhk6p/

Comment: @PremierBromanov Drawing the border beyond screen!

Comment: @RickHitchcock didn't post the font styling because I thought it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: We may need to see more CSS or HTMLto help troubleshoot.

Comment: @RickHitchcock weird, I think it is my container thats making that happen . I coudlnt recreate it on safari either https://jsfiddle.net/zdge7hdf/